Django i18n translations work locally but not when deployed in a CI/CD pipeline
I'm trying to add translations to my django project, and for some reason it never worked. When I deploy it in ci/cd pipeline not only does it not translate, but I get csrf errors, even though I got {% csrf token %} in my template and use render in my view. But all these problems disappear when I run it locally. Here's my code:
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def test_page(request):
    return render(request, "translatetest.html")

urls.py(app level)
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('test_page/', views.test_page, name='test_page'),
]

urls.py(project level)
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("i18n/", include("django.conf.urls.i18n")),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns (
    path("", include("help_pages.urls"), name="help_pages"), #test_page is here
)

settings.py
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', ('English')),
    ('fr', ('French')),
]

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

I don't think it's a problem with my python bc it worked locally but I'll put it too just in case. Also, curious enough when I deploy it in the ci/cd pipeline, only one word is translated(in another view, not the test_page one), it's not the first, just a random word gets translated.


Ensure that gettext is installed on your CI/CD environment. On
Ubuntu Server, you can install it using apt or in docker.

# Using apt
sudo apt-get install gettext
# Using Docker
...
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
   ...
    gettext\
   ...


Ensure .po files are generated locally and are present in your
source files

python manage.py makemessages --all


In your CI/CD make sure you are generating the .mo files which should come from local env
These are usually added in .gitignore file so that they get generated on the fly
python manage.py compilemessages


compilemessage alone didnt work, but after removing .mo from the gitignore, the translations worked, thanks! But one problem still stays is that I get CSRF verification failed when I try to change language

Depends on where you generating the. mo files. Its a good practice to generate the binary files on the server and not push them in your git source code.. Regarding csrf token check your middleware arrangement I don't remember well but I think the csrf middleware should come after the locale middleware
